# Two where condition for same column using group by

Tags: mysql

I am having two tables, t1, t2. My tables and expected result are given below.
My table schema is in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d511c0/1)

t1:

```
id    branch_name
1     branch1
2     branch2
3     branch3
4     branch4
5     branch5
```

t2:

```
id    VBRNCH    VTOBRN    vqty
1     1         0         10
2     2         0         20
3     3         0         30
4     0         4         40
5     0         5         50
```

Expected Result is:

```
branch_name    send    received
1               10     0
2               20     0
3               30     0
4               0      40
5               0      50
```

What i have tried is:

```
SELECT
  b1.branch_name,
  i1.vqty AS send,
  i2.vqty AS received
FROM t2 i1
INNER
JOIN t1 b1
  ON b1.id = i1.VBRNCH
INNER JOIN t2 i2
  ON b1.id = i2.VTOBRN
GROUP
BY i1.VTOBRN,
   i2.VBRNCH;
```

But I am getting zero rows.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your logic for obtaining the result.

Comment: Think you need a `left join` not a `inner join`

Comment: @MdMonjurUlHasan i added my table schema sqlfiddle in the question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the query you are looking for:

```
SELECT t1.branch_name, 
       COALESCE(SUM(send.vqty), 0) AS send, 
       COALESCE(SUM(receive.vqty), 0) AS received 
FROM t1  
LEFT JOIN t2 AS send on t1.id = send.VBRNCH  
LEFT JOIN t2 AS receive on t1.id = receive.VTOBRN 
GROUP BY t1.branch_name
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20ac0/7)

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
SELECT x.*
     , COALESCE(sent,0) sent
     , COALESCE(received,0) received
  FROM t1 x
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT from_br
            , SUM(vqty) sent
         FROM t2
        GROUP
           BY from_br
     ) a
    ON a.from_br = x.id
  LEFT
  JOIN
     ( SELECT to_br
            , SUM(vqty) received
         FROM t2
        GROUP
           BY to_br
     ) b
    ON b.to_br = x.id
 ORDER
    BY id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af0973/21